# How to add parent/child name structure to a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am fairly new to lists, previously working only with matrices and dataframes. The `createBucket()` function in the MWE code below reads the `dfList` list and creates an expanded list of dataframes comprised of the elements from "DF_One" and "DF_Two" in `dfList`. It does this correctly. However I'm having trouble with the sublist dataframe names. I can currently as the code is drafted only access dataframes by index number, such as running tmp[1] for extracting the first dataframe from the list. How do I add a parent/child structure to the naming, so for example if I run something like tmp$DF_One (or Tmp[["DF_One"]] I get all the three of the DF_One dataframes, and running tmp$DF_One$Boy gives me the "Boy" child dataframe under the "DF_One" parent dataframe?

Ideally, it would also be nice to retain the numeric indexing as an alternative way to extract sublist dataframes. If this is possible. If not possible, the most important thing is being able to access the dataframes by their character string names as described in the first paragraph.

I need good naming/indexing because ultimately the larger code this example is intended for is calculation-intensive across sublist dataframes. One column in one sublist dataframe will need to communicate with another column (or column/row combination) in another sublist dataframe in executing calculations. I need a robust naming hierarchy in order to be able to do these calculations.

Code:

```
dfVector <- function() {c("DF_One", "DF_Two")}
dfList <- list(DF_One = c("Boy", "Cat", "Dog"), DF_Two = c("Boy", "Rat", "Bat"))

createBucket <- function(nbr_rows) {
  series <- dfVector()
  series |>
    lapply(FUN = \(series_name) {
      lapply(dfList[[series_name]], \(element) {
        df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nbr_rows, 2))
        colnames(df) <- c('A', 'B')
        setNames(list(df), paste0(series_name, "_", element))
      })
    }) |>
    unlist(recursive = FALSE)
}

tmp <- createBucket(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this (modified your function)?

```
createBucket <- function(nbr_rows) {
  series <- dfVector()
  setNames(
    lapply(series, \(series_name) {
      setNames(
        lapply(dfList[[series_name]], \(element) {
          df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nbr_rows, 2))
          colnames(df) <- c('A', 'B')
          df
        }),
        dfList[[series_name]]
      )
    }),
    series
  )
}

tmp <- createBucket(5)
tmp
```

```
$DF_One
$DF_One$Boy
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0

$DF_One$Cat
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0

$DF_One$Dog
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0


$DF_Two
$DF_Two$Boy
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0

$DF_Two$Rat
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0

$DF_Two$Bat
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
```

**EDIT:** add guide to accessing values in list/sublist -

```
tmp$DF_One # renders all 3 sublists under $DF_One parent
tmp[1] # renders all 3 sublists under $DF_One including parent list name "$DF_One"
tmp[[1]] # renders all 3 sublists under $DF_One excluding parent list name "$DF_One"
tmp$DF_One[1] # renders first sublist dataframe under $DF_One parent including sublist name "Boy"
tmp$DF_One[[1]] # renders first sublist dataframe under $DF_One parent excluding sublist name "Boy"
tmp[[1]][1] # renders first sublist dataframe under $DF_One parent including sublist name "Boy"
tmp[[1]][[1]] # renders first sublist dataframe under $DF_One parent excluding sublist name "Boy"
tmp$DF_One$Cat$B[3] # access value in col B/row 3 of 2nd sublist dataframe "Cat" under parent "DF_One" 
tmp$DF_One$Cat$B <- 8 # change all values in col B of 2nd sublist dataframe "Cat" under parent "DF_One" to 8
tmp$DF_One$Cat$B[3] <- 8 # change value in col B/row 3 of 2nd sublist dataframe "Cat" under parent "DF_One" to 8
```

Comment: Works great, and I added a guide for accessing dataframes and values nested in a list. Helpful for neophytes like me.

Comment: Do you see this as a good way to organize list names, where there will be a lot of calculations and references between sublist dataframes?

Comment: For this point it is O.K. I am not that deep in your algorithm so I can't clearly answer this question!